# HtmlUnit failing when it tries to open dead javascript links. Is there a way to tell it not to load specific URLs?

Tags: java, scala, htmlunit

I'm trying to do a little scraping on [this site](http://www.eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/default.aspx) to programatically find polling info. I originally tried Python, which worked great for loading the site and navigating around the `aspx` forms, but couldn't extract the embedded maps data (since no packages (as of yet) handle javascript). So I've opted to dust off my Java skills and break out HtmlUnit. However, I almost instantly hit a snag.

It appears as though there are some dead links to javascript files on the site that don't exists. When HtmlUnit tries to load them it gets a 404 and self destructs.

#### Specific Error

```
Jul 21, 2013 9:51:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage loadExternalJavaScriptFile
SEVERE: Error loading JavaScript from [http://www.eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx/jsdebug].
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException: 404 Not Found for http://www.eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/GoogleMapForASPNet.ascx/jsdebug
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.throwFailingHttpStatusCodeExceptionIfNecessary(WebClient.java:544)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1119)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1059)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:399)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:260)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:276)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:676)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:635)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.DefaultFilter.endElement(DefaultFilter.java:206)
    at org.cyberneko.html.filters.NamespaceBinder.endElement(NamespaceBinder.java:330)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scanEndElement(HTMLScanner.java:3074)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner$ContentScanner.scan(HTMLScanner.java:2041)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLScanner.scanDocument(HTMLScanner.java:918)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:499)
    at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration.parse(HTMLConfiguration.java:452)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.parse(HTMLParser.java:892)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parse(HTMLParser.java:241)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser.parseHtml(HTMLParser.java:187)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createHtmlPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:268)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultPageCreator.createPage(DefaultPageCreator.java:156)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:434)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:374)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:359)
    at ScrapeTest$.main(ScrapeTest.scala:12)
    at ScrapeTest.main(ScrapeTest.scala)
```

Is there a way to tell it to either (a) ignore 404 errors completely, or (b) ignore specific javascript urls?

#### My Code thus far (Scala)

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage

object ScrapeTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pageurl = "http://www.eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/"
    val client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8)
    
    var response: HtmlPage = client.getPage(pageurl)
    
    println(response.asText())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A brief look at the HtmlUnit JavaDoc seems to indicate that you should be able to use [WebClientOptions#setExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(boolean)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode%28boolean%29)

e.g.,

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage

object ScrapeTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val pageurl = "http://www.eci-polldaymonitoring.nic.in/psl/"
    val client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8)
    // Don't throw exception on failing status code
    client.getOptions.setExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false)

    var response: HtmlPage = client.getPage(pageurl)

    println(response.asText())
  }
}
```

If that doesn't work you could also try:

- [WebClientOptions#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29)
- [WebClientOptions#setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(boolean)](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setThrowExceptionOnScriptError%28boolean%29)

Comment: thanks. setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false); and setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false); did it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't want that HTMLUnit is requesting external Links. Also I don't want printing out css/js warnings and all the noise.

I configured HtmlUnit (with Spring WebApplicationContext):

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
public final class _MockWebClientCreator {

  public static WebClient createWebClien(WebApplicationContext wac) {
    WebClient webClient = MockMvcWebClientBuilder.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(FALSE);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(FALSE);
    webClient.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(FALSE);
    webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
    webClient.setJavaScriptErrorListener(new SilentJavaScriptErrorListener());
    webClient.setWebConnection(new WebConnectionWrapper(webClient) { // Use only internal urls
        @Override
        public WebResponse getResponse(WebRequest request) throws IOException {
            return (startsWith(request.getUrl().toString(), "http://localhost"))
                ? super.getResponse(request)
                : new StringWebResponse("", request.getUrl());
        }
    });
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(INTEGER_ONE).toMillis());
    return webClient;
  }
}
```